# How to embed links in a Quartz PDF View

Tags: iphone, pdf, quartz-graphics

I am using Quartz to display a PDF if my iPad app rather than a webview as I dont link the borders and drop shadow effects the webview adds.

Can I still use embedded links in the PDFs? If so do I need to do anything special or will they just work?

Answer (score 0):

See this question:
[Get PDF hyperlinks on iOS with Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz)