# How does an 'annot' CGPDFDictionary 'Rect' translate to objective c Rect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, pdf, ios

How does an 'annot' CGPDFDictionary  'Rect' translate to objective c Rect:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Adobes PDF Spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) states:

> Rectangles are used to describe
>   locations on a page and bounding boxes
>   for a variety of objects. A rectangle
>   shall be written as an array of four
>   numbers giving the coordinates of a
>   pair of diagonally opposite corners.
>
> Although rectangles are conventionally
>   specified by their lower-left and
>   upper-right corners, it is acceptable
>   to specify any two diagonally opposite
>   corners. Applications that process PDF
>   should be prepared to normalize such
>   rectangles in situations where
>   specific corners are required.
>   Typically, the array takes the form
>   [llx lly urx ury] specifying the
>   lower-left x, lower-left y,
>   upper-right x, and upper-right y
>   coordinates of the rectangle, in that
>   order. The other two corners of the
>   rectangle are then assumed to have
>   coordinates (llx, ury) and (urx, lly).

So, this means that that the rect translation is not native as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz) and should be like this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[3],coords[2]-coords[0],coords[3]-coords[1]);
```

See the code Bellow (original code by [BrainFeeder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459271/brainfeeder)) to see the context of the coords array:

```
CGPDFArrayRef rectArray;
                if(CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(annotDict, "Rect", &rectArray)) {
                    //continue;

                    CGPDFReal coords[4];

                    for( int k = 0; k < arrayCount; ++k ) {

                        CGPDFObjectRef rectObj;
                        if(!CGPDFArrayGetObject(rectArray, k, &rectObj)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        CGPDFReal coord;
                        if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(rectObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeReal, &coord)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        coords[k] = coord;
                    }      

                }

                //blx,bly,trx,try>tlx,tly,w,h

                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[3],coords[2]-coords[0],coords[3]-coords[1]);
```

Comment: +1 For helping my issue, but are you sure it should not actually be:
`CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2]-coords[0],coords[3]-coords[1]);` instead of `CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[3],coords[2]-coords[0],coords[3]-coords[1]);` (note the `y` parameter; it uses the index `1` coord instead of index `3`). In any case, this worked for me.

Comment: @lindonfox, I faced with the same issues, I wand to implement select and highlight text in pdf, can you help me with it? do you have any detailed explanation how to make it or example of code?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander - in case you have not seen it yet, there is a good starting place [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints). Sorry, I don't have the time at the moment to search for specific example code.