# Get PDF GoTo Actions on iOS with Quartz

Tags: ipad, pdf, ios4, action, quartz-graphics

i´m new to apple´s core graphic for PDF. I developing an app to display a PDF with links/actions which will go to the page x/y. The first code/help i found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz). But that code is for external URLs to websites. In the pdf ref doc from Adobe.com i found out, that i have to use the "GoTo" action. I´ve tried all 3 types (object, name and byte string) but it doesn´t work. Can anyone get me a hint, what i´m doing wrong?

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < arrayCount; ++i) {
    CGPDFObjectRef aDictObj;
    if (!CGPDFArrayGetObject(outputArray, i, &aDictObj)) {          
        return;
    } // END if

    CGPDFDictionaryRef annotDict;
    if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(aDictObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary, &annotDict)) {                
        return;
    } // END if

    CGPDFDictionaryRef aDict;
    if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(annotDict, "A", &aDict)) {
        return;
    } // END if

    const char *gotoNameRef;
    CGPDFArrayRef gotoArray;        
    if (CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(aDict, "D", &gotoArray)) {  
        if (!CGPDFArrayGetName(gotoArray, 0, &gotoNameRef)) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    } // END if

    int gotoCounter = CGPDFArrayGetCount(gotoArray);

    CGPDFArrayRef rectArray;
    if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(annotDict, "Rect", &rectArray)) {
        return;
    } // END if

    int arrayCount = CGPDFArrayGetCount( rectArray );
    CGPDFReal coords[4];
    for( int k = 0; k < arrayCount; ++k ) {
        CGPDFObjectRef rectObj;
        if(!CGPDFArrayGetObject(rectArray, k, &rectObj)) {                  
            return;
        } // END if

        CGPDFReal coord;            
        if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(rectObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeReal, &coord)) {                   
            return;
        } // END if

        coords[k] = coord;
    } // END for
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PDF reader in source available here:

https://github.com/vfr/reader

It is on ObjectiveC and contains everything you need.