# What is the equivalent of CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog in Monotouch?

Tags: .net, pdf, mono, xamarin.ios, cgpdfdocument

I'm trying to get the catalog of a PDF document but I cannot find `CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog`.
Is it unbound or am I just blind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGPDFDocument::GetCatalog()** is the binding of CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog, see [github](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/059698a1b47a5c4ecd7eb1cb8692db0f998290be/src/CoreGraphics/CGPDFDocument.cs).

However I only added this recently so you'll need MonoTouch 4.1 (or more recent) or add p/invoke directly into your code.

Comment: I'll get 4.1. Do you know if there is some easy way to implement text selection in PDFs, read annotations and add annotations using MT? Maybe a free library?

Comment: I have not tried that myself but there are Q&A here on SO about annotations, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352090/how-to-get-pdf-annotations-when-i-touch-on-ipad-screen so the CodeGraphics API provided by iOS looks sufficient for (at least) that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Back then some of the methods were not bound in MT. But if you have added them now, I should be happy! :-)

Comment: I am only missing the starting point in CGPDFDictionary. All methods in there want a "key" but I cannot find anything to enumerate all keys or to get the root key or to apply a function to the dictionary's content as done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556344/create-a-table-of-contents-from-a-pdf-file with CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction.

Comment: We're abusing SO comments system ;-) since this is unrelated to the original question. Please add additional questions and I (or anyone else) will answer them, time permitting :-)