# How to iterate over CGPDFDictionary using Monotouch?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.ios, cgpdfdictionaryref

I'm using this code to get the contents of a PDF:

```
var oDoc = new CGPDFDocument.FromFile("./test.pdf");
var oCat = oDoc.GetCatalog();
```

But how do I know iterate the catalog? All methods want a "key" but I don't know how to get the root key or the array of keys.

I found that in ObjC one would use something like:

```
CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(pdfDocDictionary, ListDictionaryObjects, NULL);

void ListDictionaryObjects (const char *key, CGPDFObjectRef object, void *info) {
    NSLog("key: %s", key);
    CGPDFObjectType type = CGPDFObjectGetType(object);
    switch (type) { 
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary: {
            CGPDFDictionaryRef objectDictionary;
            if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary, &objectDictionary)) {
                CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(objectDictionary, ListDictionaryObjects, NULL);
            }
        }
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger: {
            CGPDFInteger objectInteger;
            if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger, &objectInteger)) {
                NSLog("pdf integer value: %ld", (long int)objectInteger); 
            }
        }
        // test other object type cases here
        // cf. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFObject/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001117-CH3g-SW1
    }    
}
```

See also:
[What is the equivalent of CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog in Monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257268/what-is-the-equivalent-of-cgpdfdocumentgetcatalog-in-monotouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MonoTouch (and MonoMac since this is shared code) are missing the binding for [CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html) too. Without it you need to know the **key** values that are in the dictionary.

That works well if you're looking for something specific (i.e. a well-known key value) but not if you want to inspect/show everything that exists inside a dictionary instance.

I'll look to add this binding into 'maccore' (consumed by both MonoMac and MonoTouch) and will update this entry with the binding so it can be used inside application (until fixed versions are available).

Comment: So it's a bit more involved than simple binding CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction - which I assume why it was not done earlier. It needs to provide callback to managed code, i.e. [MonoPInvokeCallback] and associated limitations, and it also require to expose CGPDFObject (which are not binded at the moment). But it will come, just don't hold your breath 'till then :)

Comment: Sebastien, we usually just hide the details about [MonoPInvokeCallback] in our bindings just expose a nice delegate as a callback.

Comment: Yep, done that (the hiding part, using an internal method which has the [MonoPInvokeCallback] and call the user method :-) but we do not expose CGPDFObject and the API is not useful without it.

Comment: I just came back from my holiday. Any news on this topic?

Comment: Miguel completed the bindings but I think it was after MonoTouch 4.2 was branched. You can see (and copy/paste) the code from https://github.com/mono/maccore/commit/ff519486c01996f64aead103d79c1764e3479450

Comment: Okay. I'm currently working on something different and hope for a new 4.2 beta (or whatever) to include it. Maybe I#ll give the file from Github a try.