# PDF Link coordinate not correct?

Tags: ios, pdf, coordinate

Please refer to [Get PDF hyperlinks on iOS with Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz/9859382#9859382)

It explained an algorithm to find the the pdf hyperlink and its coordinate.I followed this post and write my own pdf reader. It works well for most of the pdf files but not for one pdf file. The problem is the coordinate of the hyperlink is not correct.

Here is the pdf I created the hyperlink:

[image: Using Acrobat 10 to create a hyperlink in origin (0,0)]

I created a hyperlink from Adobe acrobat 10.0. The origin of this hyperlink is almost at (0,0).Then I use the algorithm to parse my pdf file. To my surprise the result rect is:

link rect = {{63, 123}, {173, -158}}

So when I render this rect in screen, it's something like this:

[image]

What could be reason? Can anybody advise? Thanks

By the way, if there is a way to upload my sample pdf file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allowed for a cropbox?

Comment: You mean inside the pdf file or in my program? Sorry, I'm quite actually very new to pdf programming

Comment: How to check if I used crop box?

Comment: CropBox is the visible area of a PDF file. It is not always the same as the mediaBox.

Comment: Yes, I found my cropBox and mediaBox is different (Is this decided when we created the pdf document?). What can I do for this? Or can you suggest where I can find some document for cropBox and mediaBox? Thanks

Comment: They are documented in the PDF reference guide.