# Display PDF with hyperlinks (like in classic redirection in summary of PDF) in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get PDF hyperlinks on iOS with Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz)

All are in title.

I want to display a PDF with hyperlinks in iPad.
At this time i have a display of PDF (page by page with 2 button that increase or decrease the current number of page in PDF) with CoreGraphic but not the hyperlink and i search a sample that make that because i don't really understand the specify of CGPDFDictionary and other function like that.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

P.S : Sorry for my bad english i am not very in this langage at this time but learn for remedy that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz

Comment: Thanks for your link that help me, i try to make the same of this solution take the url off the hyperlink and make a simple button with this url. I don't find other solution at this tima but continue to search because thats not really natural...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, rendering the PDF using a UIWebView may be a better option as link rendering will be automatic.  Keep in mind that using a UIWebView will force the entire PDF to load and it will scroll vertically as opposed to horizontally by page.

Comment: I need to have all options like page by page, all document like you suggest but the most important is the hyperlink for sumary when tap on a link you go on good page.
I read in some tuto thats impossible with simple UIWebView and only possibility is to use CoreGraphic.