# How to detect the hyperlinks in a local pdf displayed in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, datadetectortypes

I'm loading a pdf file in a `UIWebView` with the following code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pdfString] ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:req];
```

It's working fine. But I want to enable the hyperlinks in the pdf file (just like how `UITextView` detects links).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType 
{
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```