# UIPageViewController not detect links inside PDF

Tags: ios

I bought this project (http://codecanyon.net/item/turnthepdf/2417301/support) to use in my application but it is not detecting links inside PDF file. For example, page index works in webview but not working in this library.

I tried to search in internet about configuring UIPageViewController but no result.

```
#pragma mark Debug / Utility
- (int) currentPage
{
    int pageCheck = ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view.tag;
    return pageCheck;
}

#pragma mark Page Handling

// Update if you'd rather use some other decision style
- (BOOL) useSideBySide: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation
{
    BOOL isLandscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
    return isLandscape;
}


// Store the new page and update the delgate
- (void) updatePageTo: (uint) newPageNumber
{
    pageNumber = newPageNumber;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:pageNumber forKey:DEFAULTS_BOOKPAGE];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    SAFE_PERFORM_WITH_ARG(bookDelegate, @selector(bookControllerDidTurnToPage:), [NSNumber numberWithInt:pageNumber]);
}

// Request controller from delegate
- (UIViewController *) controllerAtPage: (int) aPageNumber
{
    if (bookDelegate && 
        [bookDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllerForPage:)])
    {
        UIViewController *controller = [bookDelegate viewControllerForPage:aPageNumber];
        controller.view.tag = aPageNumber;
        return controller;
    }

    return nil;
}

// Update interface to the given page
- (void) fetchControllersForPage: (uint) requestedPage orientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation
{   
    BOOL sideBySide = [self useSideBySide:orientation];
    int numberOfPagesNeeded = sideBySide ? 2 : 1;
    int currentCount = self.viewControllers.count;

    uint leftPage = requestedPage;
    if (sideBySide && (leftPage % 2)) leftPage--;

    // Only check against current page when count is appropriate
    if (currentCount && (currentCount == numberOfPagesNeeded))
    {
        if (pageNumber == requestedPage) return;
        if (pageNumber == leftPage) return;
    }

    // Decide the prevailing direction by checking the new page against the old
    UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection direction = (requestedPage > pageNumber) ? UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse;
    [self updatePageTo:requestedPage];


    // Update the controllers
    NSMutableArray *pageControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    SAFE_ADD(pageControllers, [self controllerAtPage:leftPage]);    
    if (sideBySide)
        SAFE_ADD(pageControllers, [self controllerAtPage:leftPage + 1]);

    [self setViewControllers:pageControllers direction: direction animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {


}


// Entry point for external move request
- (void) moveToPage: (uint) requestedPage
{
    [self fetchControllersForPage:requestedPage orientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
}


#pragma mark Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    [self updatePageTo:pageNumber - 1];
    return [self controllerAtPage:(viewController.view.tag - 1)];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self updatePageTo:pageNumber + 1];
    return [self controllerAtPage:(viewController.view.tag + 1)];

}

/*
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self updatePageTo:pageNumber + 1];
    return [self controllerAtPage:(viewController.view.tag + 1)];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self updatePageTo:pageNumber - 1];
    return [self controllerAtPage:(viewController.view.tag - 1)];
}

*/


#pragma mark Delegate

- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

    NSUInteger indexOfCurrentViewController = 0;
    if (self.viewControllers.count)
        indexOfCurrentViewController = ((UIViewController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view.tag;
    [self fetchControllersForPage:indexOfCurrentViewController orientation:orientation];

    BOOL sideBySide = [self useSideBySide:orientation];
    self.doubleSided = sideBySide;

    UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation spineLocation = sideBySide ? UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid : UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
    return spineLocation;
}



#pragma mark Class utility routines
// Return a UIViewController that knows how to rotate
+ (id) rotatableViewController
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[RotatableVC alloc] init];
    return vc;
}




// Return a new book
+ (id) bookWithDelegate: (id) theDelegate
{
    BookController *bc = [[BookController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    bc.dataSource = bc;
    bc.delegate = bc;
    bc.bookDelegate = theDelegate;

    return bc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations inside a pdf is not able to render in iOS devices to render forms or annotations you can go for a good library.

[Pdf Tron Library](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/ios_pdf_library.html)

You can also see the below link it might help.

[Get pdf hyperlinks on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz)